# Convert save implementation to generic way

Tags: java, generics

I tried to use a generic way to save entity, there is a converstion phase to be done.

i try to put my save method in a abstract class

```
public class SportsServiceImpl extends BaseService implements SportsService {

        public void save(SportsDto SportsDto) {

            Sports Sports = null;

            if (SportsDto == null) {
                //throw error
            }

            if (SportsDto.getId() != null) {
                Optional<Sports> SportsOpt = SportsRepository.findById(SportsDto.getId());

                if (SportsOpt.isPresent()) {
                    Sports = SportsOpt.get();
                }
            }

            if (Sports == null) {
                Sports = new Sports();
            }

            convertToBeans(SportsDto, Sports);

            SportsRepository.save(Sports);

     }

}
```

try to put here

```
public abstract class BaseService<T> {

    private JpaRepository<T, Integer> repository;

        public <T extends BaseEntity, R  extends BaseDto> void save(R r){
        T t = null;

        if (r == null) {
            //throw error
        }

        if (r.getId() != null) {
            Optional<T> tOpt = null;
            try {
                tOpt = (Optional<T>) repository.findById(t.getClass().getField("id").getInt(t));
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BaseService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            if (tOpt!=null && tOpt.isPresent()) {
                t = tOpt.get();
            }
        }

        if (t == null) {
            t = new T();           //seem not able to do this
        }

        convertToBeans(r, t);   //java don't like that

        repository.save(t);
    }
```

convertToBeans is in the class who extends BaseService

Tried to pass in parameer of save Function convertToBeans

but get same result

is there a way to do it in a generic way

Comment: add a constructor that takes a `Class<T>` as parameter and use this `newInstance()` on this `Class<T>` for the `new T()` is the *usual* way. For the `convertToBeans` part, information is missing..

Comment: Please show method declaration of `convertToBeans`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your convertion method abstract:

```
public abstract class BaseService<T, R> {

private JpaRepository<T, Integer> repository;

    public <T extends BaseEntity, R  extends BaseDto> void save(R r){
    T t = null;

    if (r == null) {
        //throw error
    }

    if (r.getId() != null) {
        Optional<T> tOpt = null;
        try {
            tOpt = (Optional<T>) repository.findById(t.getClass().getField("id").getInt(t));
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BaseService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        if (tOpt!=null && tOpt.isPresent()) {
            t = tOpt.get();
        }
    }

    repository.save(convertToBeans(r));
    }

public abstract T convertToBeens(R dto);
}
```

Comment: `convertToBeans` called in `repository.save`, and creation of T will be inside of this method, as it is abstract you will create it in each instance of your BaseService where you will knew real type not some generic T.

Comment: convertToBeans receive two parameter not one.... so that change your flow... second save(t) don't work.... expect s...